# Is there a secondary way to check whether I have voicemail if the phone application is not registering correctly?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, voicemail

After the August Marshmallow Android OS update, I realized I had unheard voicemail messages. These messages had neither shown up as notifications on my phone nor appeared under the visual voicemail tab of the phone application prior to the update, and I think they extend back to my last Android OS update (roughly one month ago). Obviously, it is a problem if the phone application does not register that there are voicemail messages.

Is there a secondary way to check whether I have voicemail? I would strongly prefer a method that does not require manually dialing into my voicemail to check.

Comment: You could try [Free Visual voicemail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.freemobile.android.vvm) . It claims to visually display voice mails. Not tried by me. As am interim measure to it is fixed

Comment: @beeshyams "This application is only for users of french "Free" mobile operator", which is not my wireless service provider.

Comment: Oops. My bad. Sorry.Maybe this can help https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gabriloware.notifier.voicemail